# Prosody/Pidgin not sending buddy authorization requests

Tags: xmpp, instant-messaging, pidgin, prosody-im

I'm setting up a Prosody XMPP server on my local machine for a proof of concept, and I just want to get a simple chat session going with myself. I set it to allow registration, and was able to register new users, but when I send a buddy request to one of the other users I've registered, he doesn't get it, and all users, including myself, show as "Not Authorized" in Pidgin.

I'm "test2" on my local machine, and on another machine, I'm logged in as "test3". When I send a buddy request from test2 to test3, nothing happens.

In Pidgin, the only log I see is

```
---- +++ test2@pc-705.example.com/ signed on @ 11/20/2015 2:32:19 PM ----
```

where example.com is my domain.

My Prosody log just says that I've authenticated but does not mention sending buddy requests:

```
C:\Users\test2\Desktop\XMPP\Prosody>prosody.bat
general             info        Hello and welcome to Prosody version 0.9.7
general             info        Prosody is using the select backend for connecti
on handling
localhost:tls       error       Unable to initialize TLS: No SSL/TLS configurati
on present for localhost
localhost:tls       error       Unable to initialize TLS: No SSL/TLS configurati
on present for localhost
portmanager         info        Activated service 's2s' on [::]:5269, [*]:5269
mod_s2s             warn        No local IPv4 or IPv6 addresses detected, outgoi
ng connections may fail
portmanager         info        Activated service 'c2s' on [::]:5222, [*]:5222
portmanager         info        Activated service 'legacy_ssl' on no ports
pc-705.example.com:tls  error     Unable to initialize TLS: No SSL/TLS configuration present for pc-705.example.com
pc-705.example.com:tls  error     Unable to initialize TLS: No SSL/TLS configuration present for pc-705.example.com
c2s02310338                   info      Client connected
c2s02310338                   info      Authenticated as test2@pc-705.example.com
c2s0                          info      Client connected
c2s0                          info      Authenticated as test3@pc-705.example.com
```

Where is my issue?

Comment: Where did you see that message in pidgin? The chat window? How did you try to add your `test3` buddy to your buddy list? Did you add `test3`? Did you add `test3@pc-705.example.com`?

Comment: In Pidgin, Tools -> System Logs. To add users, under Modify Account, check the "Create this new account on the server" box and save. To add buddies to my list, Buddies -> Add Buddy then added test3. And finally, I got to your last question and that worked! I did not have the domain on there. Put it in an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Oh, the system log is largely useless (and off by default I think). The Help->Debug Window is *infinitely* more useful for debugging all things pidgin.

Comment: Just checked that out, it is certainly more useful than the system log. Thanks for that advice. With my PoC complete, I'm going to start ramping up to a much more complicated server environment, so that will definitely come in handy. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah, for XMPP especially the debug window output is fantastic as it includes the entire communication with the server. The "System Log" is an ancient artifact that has just never been killed because every time it comes up *someone* inevitably mentions that they love it and use it all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have tried adding the buddy as `test3`. Which isn't going to work. A buddy on XMPP is `user@server`.

You need to add them as `test3@pc-705.example.com` or whatever.

This is part of how/why XMPP server's can federate (interoperate). Like email.